# How volley synchronously work in android

Tags: android, android-volley

How volley library work synchronously in android? I want when volley get response from server for that time execution of program stop and wait for result from volley.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can show loader for that particular time as below:

```
 public void getResult() {
        try {
            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();

            StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MapAppConstant.API , new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("", ".......response====" + response.toString());

                    ////////
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        String serverCode = object.getString("code");
                        String serverMessage = object.getString("message");
                        //  Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "" + serverMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                        }
                        if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            try {

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
                    , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    //  VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Timeout Error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    params.put("user_language", prefshelper.getUserLanguageFromPreference());


                    return params;
                }
            };
            sr.setShouldCache(true);

            sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000 * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(HomeActivity.this.getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(sr);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, this one can't work synchronously this work asynchronously how this answer help me.

Comment: @TejaBatth But you can't stop a program. You can use thread for sleep i think.